# i am using parse so is their any way to get notification when my app will exceed access limit?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I get the exception that the application has exceeded the request limit. error code i s 155 so now i want that whenever it goes to exceed the limit my app should notify is their any way to get this?

Comment: You can catch the Exception and then create a Toast

Comment: Thanks.. :) @ Musterknabe

Comment: for the user we can do this but how would i know that my app limit is exceeding ?

Comment: Well, just send an email to you? Or something like that. It's up to you what you do

Answer (score 0):

Basically, as I said in my comment. Try-catch Block

```
try {
    // code goes here
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // You can also do switch/case here or sth. like that to check if its the rate limit error
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 'Rate limit exceeded', 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
}
```

With this way, when an Exception happens you `catch` it, meaning you can handle the error and do something else instead of crashing your application. In this example we will continue with the rest of the application but also display a toast message to the user, to tell him that the Rate Limit has been exceeded. What you do afterwards, or how you handle it then, is up to you